# WhenEvent in NDSolve -management of accuracy

Tags: differential-equations, precision-and-accuracy

I am bouncing a particle off various surfaces and using `WhenEvent` to determine when I hit the surface.  Here are some very simple examples for when things go correctly or incorrectly.
Here is a working example where I am bouncing of walls at x = 0 and x = 1:

```
sol = First@NDSolve[
    {x''[t] == 0, x[0] == 0.5, x'[0] == -0.2,
     WhenEvent[{x[t] == 0, x[t] == 1}, x'[t] -> -x'[t]]
     },
    x,
    {t, 0, 50}];
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. First@sol], {t, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

This has worked correctly and continues to work if the duration is set to a much longer time.

Edit: There was a second case but with a simple error so now removed.

I need to have different actions for each wall so I wrote a module called bounce that enables me to take different actions on each wall. This does not work either.

```
ClearAll[bounce];

    bounce[x_, v_] := Module[{u},
       Which[x == 0., u = -v,
        x == 1., u = -v,
        True, Print[{"No match", x, v}]; Sow[x]]; u];
    
    {sol, events} = Reap[First@NDSolve[
         {x''[t] == 0, x[0] == 0.5, x'[0] == -0.2,
          WhenEvent[{x[t] == 0., x[t] == 1.}, {v = bounce[x[t], x'[t]]; 
            x'[t] -> v}]
          },
         x,
         {t, 0, 50}, InterpolationOrder -> All, 
         Method -> "ImplicitRungeKutta"]];
```

[image]

The problem here is that the accuracy of the `WhenEvent` is not up to my sorting in bounce. We can see this from the sow value

```
events[[1, 1]] == 0.
```

[image]

There are two solutions to my problem that I can suggest.

1. Is there an easy way of associating events with individual actions? Can you have several `WhenEvents` one for each wall?
2. Inside my bounce module I allow for an error in the accuracy of `WhenEvent`.

Are there any more approaches?

Comment: You say the second example does not do what you want, but it bounces off the wall at $x=0$, just as I would expect. (If I throw a ball at a wall, it won't hit the wall behind it.)  -- Another point: It's best not to compare floating-point numbers with equal, esp. `...== 0.`. Nonzero numbers are compared with tolerance in Mma, so you can sometimes get away with it. A standard approach for `a == b` is `Abs[a-b] < tolerance` for some appropriate choice of `tolerance`. `NDSolve` itself uses [`ScaledVectorNorm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveVectorNorm.html) to measure error

Comment: @cvgmt Yes an incorrect wall condition. Should be x == 1. Rats!  My mistake Could you confirm that it is therefore possible to use several `WhenEvent`s to associate with several different actions?  Question edited.

Comment: @MichaelE2  You are correct about the second example. Wall at wrong location. However, I still need to have different actions for different walls. So what is the best way of doing this? Your tolerance idea is probably the way I need to go.

Comment: Question edited. Second case was wrong.

Comment: I find it confusing that your `bounce[]` does the same thing for `x == 0` and `x == 1`. I thought you wanted different actions, like this: `NDSolve[{x''[t] == 0, x[0] == 0.5, x'[0] == -0.92,
  WhenEvent[x[t] == 0., x'[t] -> -0.5 x'[t]],
  WhenEvent[x[t] == 1., x'[t] -> -2 x'[t]]}, x, {t, 0, 10}]`

Comment: In `Which[]` in `bounce[]`, replacing `x == 0.` by `x + 1. == 1.` (absolute tolerance) or `x + Abs[v] == Abs[v]` (tolerance proportional to `v`) works on the example.

Answer (score 1):

A simple alternative would be the "mechanical" definition of a contact force at `x==0`and `x==1` :

```
c = 1000; (* stiffness contact *)
X  = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] ==Which[x[t] <= 0, -c x[t], x[t] >= 1, -c  x[t]], x[0] == 0.5,x'[0] == -0.2 }, x, {t, 0, 50}];
Plot[X[t]  , {t, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The OP says different actions are required at each wall, even though the example `bounce[]` takes the same action at both walls.  So here's an example, which seems an easiest way to have different actions, in this case different bouncing coefficients:

```
NDSolveValue[{x''[t] == 0, x[0] == 0.5, x'[0] == -0.92,
  WhenEvent[x[t] == 0., x'[t] -> -x'[t]],
  WhenEvent[x[t] == 1., x'[t] -> -0.7 x'[t]]},
 x, {t, 0, 20}]
% // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

It reflects perfectly elastically off the top wall, but loses 30% of its velocity off the bottom wall.